# Maximum Likelihood Estimator of $f(x;\theta) = (1/\theta)x^{(1-\theta)/\theta} $

Tags: statistics

Let $f(x;\theta) = (1/\theta)x^{(1-\theta)/\theta} $$\hspace{20 mm}$ $   0 <x <1 ,\hspace{5 mm} 0 <\theta<\infty$

I need to show that the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta $ is $\hat{\theta}$ = $-(1/n) \sum ln  X_i$

I'm having trouble with some of the steps.

Comment: *Which steps?* **Hint**: $(1-\theta)/\theta = 1/\theta - 1$.

Comment: having trouble at the derivative of $L(\theta|x)$

Comment: So what is your $L(\theta|x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an i.i.d copy of $X_i \sim f_\theta(X) = \frac{1}{\theta}x^{(1-\theta)/\theta)}I_{\{ x \in (0,1), \theta>0\}}$ and  $i=1, ... , n$ then the log-likelihood is

$$ \mathcal{l}(\theta)  = \log(\prod_{i=1}^n f_\theta(x_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(f_\theta(x_i)) = -n \log(\theta) + (1-\theta)/\theta \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)  $$

$$\partial \mathcal l(\theta) = -\frac{n}{\theta} -  \frac{1}{\theta^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i) = 0 $$
Then 
$$ \hat \theta  =  - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)\quad \square $$